# Destroying Class pointers with STL Queue pop()

Tags: c++, pointers

What happen when you get a pointer through `some_queue.front()`, assign it to another variable, and then call `some_queue.pop()`? Who is supposed to cleanup the memory? (I am using c++98, I can use boost smart pointers if really needed)

Ex: (Why does this work? or is it not supposed to?)

```
class SClass {
public:
    SClass(int si): sInt(si){}
    int getSInt(){ return sInt; }

private:
    int sInt;
    ... // bunch of other complicated data types so copy might be slow
};

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   queue<SClass *> sq;
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       SClass *sc = new SClass(i);
       sq.push(sc);
   }
   SClass *s2 = NULL;
   while(!sq.empty()){
       s2 = sq.front();
       sq.pop();
       cout << s2->getSInt() << endl;
   }
   delete s2;
   return 0;
}
```

Working test code here: http://cpp.sh/6z7ke

Comment: You must delete (clean up) it yourself. In this example, you forgot to clean up 9 `SClass`. Why do you use `queue<SClass*>`? Why don't just `queue<SClass>`

Comment: Destroying a pointer does not have any effects on what it points to. Now, all containers are just containers for their actual type, they don't care if the type is a pointer and behave differently for them. This follows the principle of least surprise.

Comment: Duh! sorry..! this is a stupid question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, the `queue` only manage the pointers themselves, it does not do anything with the memory it points to. In your example, you leak the nine first `SClass` and only delete the last one.

You shouldn't dynamically allocate your objects if you don't *explicitly* need it. Try this:

```
int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   queue<SClass> sq;
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       sq.push(i);
   }

   while(!sq.empty()){
       SClass& s2 = sq.front();
       cout << s2.getSInt() << endl;
       sq.pop();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

In this case, the objects are created when `push`ed to the queue, and destroyed when `pop`ed. If we ignore the possible performance hiccup (a temporary `SClass` is created as an argument to `queue.push()` and the copied to the queue internal buffer; this can be optimized but it's another topic), this is a way more clean, readable approach.

---

If your objects are big and you want to be sure they are not uselessly copied, you should either use a `std::queue<std::unique_ptr<SClass>>` or provide a move constructor for `SClass`. This is a bit out of scope here, so I'll let you ask another question if need be.

Comment: Is it supposed to be  `sq.push(i);` or  `sq.push(SClass(i));` ?

Comment: `sq.push(i);` implicitly creates a `SClass(i)` and `push`es it. The two writings are equivalent here.

Comment: Also, the reason I was reluctant to use objects is that they can be pretty big. But I assume in this case you are using only a temporary object and it is not really "copied" Is that right? And what about when it's retrieved? Would the compiler optimize it given that I call `pop()` right after `front()`?

Answer (score 3):

> What happen when you get a pointer through some_queue.front(), assign it to another variable, and then call some_queue.pop()?

A copy of the object is stored in the *another variable* and it's removed from the top of the queue.

> Who is supposed to cleanup the memory?

Whoever allocated the memory.

> Why does this work?

At a quick glance, there doesn't seem any reason why it wouldn't *work*. You do leak most of the allocated `SClass` objects however (all except the bottom one). To fix the leak, delete the pointer that you got from the queue before it is reassigned to another value (at the end of the loop). Better yet, don't allocate memory manually and use a queue of objects instead of queue of pointers.

Answer (score 3):

`std::queue::pop()` would not release memory if contained element type is of pointer. User must ensure to free memory owned by raw-pointers in case of all standard containers.

```
while(!sq.empty()){
       s2 = sq.front();
       sq.pop();
       cout << s2->getSInt() << endl;

       // memory should be freed here
       delete s2;
   }
```